# azure Terraform parameter with CSV file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-openstack

I'm trying to access terraform variable data using CSV file, have creating resource group and the name of resource group are added into the CSV file and trying to access into code.

Here is the code :

```
locals {
  Resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/onkar.csv"))
}

//Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11" {
  count    = length(local.Resource_groupname)
  name     = local.Resource_groupname[count.index].resourcegroup_name
  location = "North europe"
}
```

I get the following error :

```
on admin.tf line 15, in resource "azurerm_resource_group"
"Customer11":   15:   name     =
local.Resource_groupname[count.index].resourcegroup_name
     |----------------
     | local.Resource_groupname is list of object with 1 element
This object does not have an attribute named "resourcegroup_name".
```

Updated

[This is error SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vns2h.png)

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfNfc.png)

```
Updated Code: 

  locals {
  Resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
  }
  resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11" {
  count    = length(local.Resource_groupname)
  name     = local.Resource_groupname[count.index].group_names 
  location = "North europe"
  }
```

New Updated

```
 locals {
      Resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
    }

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11" {
      count    = length(local.Resource_groupname)
      name     =  local.Resource_groupname[count.index].Resource_groupname   
      location = "North europe"
    }
```

New update CSV file and output

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfNfc.png)

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwoOO.png)

Comment: The error is clear : You don't have an object called `local.Resource_groupname.resourcegroup_name`, you only defined an object called `local.Resource_groupname`. Where this `resourcegroup_name` is coming from ?

Comment: the resource group name is coming from CSV file I have store the name in CSV file and the resource group name is Column name.

Comment: How does the csv file looks like?

Comment: same as excel the extension is CSV UTF-8(comma delimited) format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the input from the CSV file, I assume your CSV file with only one line and it looks like this:

```
test1,test2,test3
```

Then you can load and use them from the CSV file as below:

```
locals {
  group_names = split(",", file("./test.csv"))
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11" {
  count    = length(local.group_names)
  name     = local.group_names[count.index]
  location = "North europe"
}
```

If you use the CSV file like this:

```
resource_group_name
test1
test2
test3
```

Then the terraform code should change into this:

```
locals {
  group_names = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  count       = length(local.group_names)
  name        = local.group_names[count.index].resource_group_name
  location    = "East US"
}
```

**Update:**

With the CSV file you provide, you need to change the resource group name like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11" {
  count    = length(local.Resource_groupname)
  name     = local.Resource_groupname[count.index].group_names   # here is the change
  location = "North europe"
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the CSV file:

[image]

You can try to output the `local.Resource_groupname` to see what it looks like when you load the data from the CSV file.

**Update2**

I really do not understand why you cannot figure out how to do it. Here is the screenshot of my test for all the things, hope you solve it:

The content of the Terraform file and the CSV.

[image]

The Terraform plan:

[image]

Comment: The second code is showing same error agian @Charles XU






**Error: Unsupported attribute

  on admin.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main":
  14:   name        = local.group_names[count.index].resource_group_name
    |----------------
    | local.group_names is list of object with 3 elements

This object does not have an attribute named "resource_group_name".**

Comment: I have try both code  its showing the same error again. 

first code is showing the following error, i have save CSV file content as per your method.

**"Error: "name" may only contain alphanumeric characters, dash, underscores, parentheses and periods

  on admin.tf line 12, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11":
  12: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11" {"**

Comment: @terraform-ninja Just show the CSV file. I cannot figure it out without a message.

Comment: I  have added same content which you provided in top of second solution like resourcegroup name  and after thet in a single column add the data like test1,test2,test3 and after that save the excel file as CSV UTF-8(comma delimited) format...

Comment: @terraform-ninja The values you said test1,test2,test3 should be input in every line, not in one line. Does it? I need to say again, the names `group_names` is the array name in the `locals` block. And the `resource_group_name` is the name you set in the CSV file first line.

Comment: yes,I have try that also but its not working showing same error... the object does not have attribute name

Comment: @terraform-ninja Just give your CSV file in the question!

Comment: ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/154uLz_zYA3JzxvfOhZqS6MU4nOgLs_ck/view?usp=sharing )   this is link of CSV file

Comment: @terraform-ninja Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: i have try with updated code but the error is not resolves same error is occurred.

Comment: @terraform-ninja I can't believe it. What I showed you is that it does and it works fine on my side. I will give the screenshot of the CSV file that what it should be.

Comment: I have update the Code, CSV file and error in TOP please Check it. i have try but  not working

Comment: @terraform-ninja The attribute is the name that you set in the CSV file at the first line. Do not change it every time when I told you how to do it.

Comment: yes I have try as per your instruction but its not working. showing same error

Comment: @terraform-ninja I just cannot believe. If the updates you put is what you using current, you need to quote locals as `local.Resource_groupname[count.index].Resource_groupname`. Don't change the CSV file again.

Comment: not working showing same error -This object does not have an attribute named "Resource_groupname".

Comment: @terraform-ninja Did you change the CSV file? Just show the output of the locals!

Comment: as per your instruction i have not changed the CSV file , update CSV file in yop and code also

Comment: @terraform-ninja I mean can you share the local.Resource_groupname that you load from the CSV file. I want to see what do you load.

Comment: i want to assign that CSV file resource group parameter to resource group name when i deploy this code automatically the resource group name parameter take the value from CSV

Comment: @terraform-ninja Yeah, do you try the way I provided in the answer before the update. I mean all the things are the same as mine, CSV file, and the local block.

Comment: yes @Charles i have try with all updated tricks but its not working.

Comment: @terraform-ninja Just change the Terraform to add the `output "resource_groups" { value=local.Resource_groupname}` to let me see what do you load from the CSV file.

Comment: @terraform-ninja Any more questions? Do you solve the problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: there no use of output showing same error i have check with the code

Comment: could you show me screen shot of your terraform plan screen...please

Comment: @terraform-ninja See the updates. That is all the things I can do for you. Good luck!

Comment: i really confused what happen with me i have tried same code, which terraform version you used.

Comment: @terraform-ninja Terraform 0.12.19. You can show the output of the locals so that I can see what do you load from the CSV.

Comment: hello Charles,  its working now thank you so much for help

Comment: @terraform-ninja Tha's really a happy thing. Then you can accept it as the answer when it solves your problem.

Comment: @terraform-ninja You're welcome. If I can know what makes it does not work before?

Comment: yes, i changed extension of CSV file (comma delimited) and its work

Comment: hello @Charles have one query, how the resource group name is define in virtual network to deploy in same RG using same local method?

Comment: @terraform-ninja I'm not clear what the most you want. Can you post another question with more messages to describe what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem apparently, it won't read the first column for some reason you can just shift all the data to one column right leaving the first column blank. Worked for me.