# Azure terraform parameter with two csv files not working

Tags: azure, csv, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I followed the same suggestions from [azure Terraform parameter with CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986320/azure-terraform-parameter-with-csv-file), but somehow not working for me.

In my case I have 2 csv files, one is test.csv [test.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bar6S.png) and other is client.csv [client.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnCs.png)

my main.tf contains [main.tf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK5OG.png)

I'm trying to add all variables in the client.csv file to "name" in the resource and tried different methods to do it. one of them is \ name = local.group_names[count.index].resource_group_name - var.clientname \

Getting the following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMeEQ.png)

Is there a way to add 'clientname' in the client.csv file to the name in the resource along with 'resource_group_name'

Comment: Provide the whole Terraform code in the question. We need more details.

Comment: Added more info. @CharlesXu

Answer (score 0):

In your Terraform file that you provided, I can see only one mistake, it's the error shows you. So just change the code like this:

```
locals {
  group_names = "${csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))}"
  client_names = "${csvdecode(file("./client.csv"))}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  count       = length(local.group_names)
  name        = "${local.group_names[count.index].resource_group_name}-${var.clientname}"
  location    = "East US"
}
```

I'm pretty sure, the code shown above works well. And the blackspace should not put in the string for the name. And the Terraform and Azure versions are here:

```
Terraform v0.12.19
+ provider.azurerm v2.7.0
```

Comment: Yes, It's only working when I'm giving a default value in variable.tf and overriding with tfvars, The clientname value should come from client.csv file. If we do the way you suggested, I can only create 3 resources as per my test.csv. but I should be able to create 6 resources if my clientname comes from the client.csv file.

Comment: @user13414765 The code you use does not achieve the function you want. It did what it should do. It's your problem, not the code.

Comment: @user13414765 Any more questions?