# Experiencing an error when try to output content of a csv file using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider-openstack

I'm trying to use terraform variable data (CSV file) to create a resource group and the name of the resource group is added into the CSV file. I'm currently experiencing the below error

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on testtf.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main":
│   11:       name     =  local.resource_groupname[count.index].groupname
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ local.resource_groupname is list of object with 3 elements
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "groupname".

Code

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}

locals {
      resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
    }

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main" {
      count    = length(local.resource_groupname)
      name     =  local.resource_groupname[count.index].groupname   
      location = "North europe"
    }
```

./test.csv content

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ituKDzaMVXnyynkjLBZRzMdWK9tnkL14/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see any reason why it woudn't work. Maybe, just like before, you  posted wrong code, wrong error message or wrong csv file. Please double check.

Comment: The information is correct this time.

I can across something similar to my concern on this like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986320/azure-terraform-parameter-with-csv-file, but I the solution was not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the file you provided has UTF BOM (Byte Order Mark) bytes that cause TF and/or Azure to choke.

I recreated the csv file as plain ascii and your HCL worked ok

I found out about the extra characters by using `terraform console`. It is a very simple and quick way to troubleshoot TF errors.

I used this really basic .tf file to check the `cvsdecode()` behavior.  (test0.csv below is your original file and test.csv my created from scratch text file):

```
locals {
      resource_groupname0 = csvdecode(file("./test0.csv"))
      resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
 }
```

Run terraform console and inspect the local variables. Note the BOM characters before "groupname" (test0.csv):

```
$ terraform console
> local.resource_groupname0
tolist([
  {
    "\ufeffgroupname" = "test11"
  },
  {
    "\ufeffgroupname" = "test12"
  },
  {
    "\ufeffgroupname" = "test13"
  },
])
> local.resource_groupname
tolist([
  {
    "groupname" = "test11"
  },
  {
    "groupname" = "test12"
  },
  {
    "groupname" = "test13"
  },
])
```

Also using the unix file command:

```
## Your file
$ file test0.csv
test0.csv: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators

## Created by hand with text editor
$ file test.csv
test.csv: ASCII text
```

Comment: This actually helped.....

What I just did was save the file as a comma-delimited format and it worked fine.

Comment: glad it did.  pls mark answer as useful to help other people who may have the same issue